# Block a specific file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use `mod_rewrite` to block access to a file.

Let's say `index.html` as an example.

I know you can use `FileMatch` but I want to use `mod_rewrite` to do this.

I tried doing something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.html$
RewriteRule (.*) - [L]
```

But that doesn't work, how to I archive that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `F` flag to deny access to a given file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [F]
```

Deny access to any file that ends with `.pdf`:

```
RewriteRule \.pdf$ - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file used to exist there are a couple of options. Rather than saying *"Access Denied"* to the browser, search engine, or user. If you removed the file and have no other file to takes it's place then you can respond with a `410 Gone` error by using the `G` flag.

```
RewriteRule ^yourfile.html$ - [G,L]
```

If it's in some directory, then you have to include the directory as well, but since we're using `.htaccess` we won't need the preceding slash.

```
RewriteRule ^some-directory/yourfile.html$ - [G,L]
```

If you've moved the file, then you can respond with a `301 Redirect` response to let the users, search engines, and everyone else know that the file has a new permanent location

```
RewriteRule ^old-directory/yourfile.html$ new-directory/yourfile.html [R=301,L]
```

If you want to tell people that the file still exists but they can not access it because it's now privileged, then you can make the request for the file respond with `403 forbidden`.

```
RewriteRule ^some-directory/yourfile.html$ - [F,L]
```

You can learn [more about the various rewrite flags on this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html).